# single jax-rs service return table data by table name

Tags: web-services, rest, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I want to write a jersey web service which can return table data from database by table name
URL would be like : /rest/{table}

For example if my database contains A, B , C tables then  request url would be
/rest/A , /rest/B and rest/C  and it will return respective table data , i am using spring data jpa.

my current solutions is just check table name and call respective service and return data but in case more table there will be many if statements so i am confused how i can write in better way so a single   service can handle it as in future there may be more tables.

Please give me some idea to proceed with it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like a poor design. I would create a class for each table/collection. Make the URIs static to retrieve the entire collection i.e. `/rest/A` where `@Path("/A")` will be the top level path for class `A`. You could make a base abstract class that contains common crud operations that your resource classes extend from. There shouldn't be a need for a bunch of ifs in the base class methods if you use an ORM framework like JPA to handle the type retrievals of collections.

Comment: The point is not to have a single resources classes for a bunch of non related types. You're going to end up with a huge class, as your different type may requires different operations

Comment: One design possibility for the base abstract class is to have a `Class` field and a constructor that accepts the `Class` type. For each resource class, `super(...)` with the entity `Class`. That way all the methods in the abstract class can act off that class passed to it. No ifs needed. All your JPA operations will be typed